# Fire only once if key is found inside a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, each

I have a JSON object of products. Within the object I want to check if any of the products have the `featured` key set to `true`. If the key exists anywhere within the object, I want to add an `h3` above the results one single time.

Let's say I have an object with 4 products and one of those products has the `featured` key set to `true`, how would I adjust this code so that the h3 only gets added once(currently it's being added all 4 times)?

```
var searchResult = '';
$.each(products, function (id, product) {
    if (products[id].featured) { searchResult += '<h3>Featured</h3>'; }
});
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON object. You either have a string of JSON, or a JavaScript object (literal). As for your question: `if (products.some(p => p.featured)) ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `return false` inside `$.each` callback to break the loop

```
var searchResult = '';
$.each(products, function (id, product) {
    if (products[id].featured) { 
        searchResult += '<h3>Featured</h3>'; 
        return false;
    }       
});
```

You could shorten this up a bit by using `Array#find()` or `Array#some()` instead

```
var searchResult = '';
var featured =  products.some(function(prod){ return prod.featured});
if(featured){
   searchResult += '<h3>Featured</h3>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have a variable to keep the `featured` state for you and modify it in the loop if there's a match

```
var searchResult = '';
var featured = false;
$.each(products, function (id, product) {
    if (products[id].featured) { featured = true; }
});

if(featured === true){
    searchResult += '<h3>Featured</h3>';
}
```

Comment: 1. `if (product.featured)` 2. `if (featured)` 3. [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) 4. exit the loop using `return false;`

Comment: Seems unnecessary to continue looping through products after finding one that satisfies the criteria. If there are 1000 products and the first one is featured, you're doing 999 iterations too many.

Comment: If that's the only purpose of the function yes. But I can image OP using a loop already to go through all the elements and just wanting to add the extra functionality to it. That's the situation this answer would be helpful, otherwise @charlietfl's answer would be better.